# Can I use microtype (or something else) to 'amend' a ligature's spacing?

Tags: spacing, microtype, ligatures

Say I have the following source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \Dash { } {
  \leavevmode
  \unskip
  \nobreak
  \hspace{\halfspace}
  \textemdash
  \hspace{\halfspace}
}
\NewDocumentCommand \halfspace { } {
  .5\fontdimen2\font plus .5\fontdimen3\font minus .5\fontdimen4\font
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumped---%
  and I mean \emph{bounded}---%
  over that lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumped \Dash
  and I mean \emph{bounded} \Dash
  over that lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

How can I get the effect of using `\Dash` (not necessarily just using that control sequence, just appropriately altering the spacing) by only using the syntax in the first sample?

---

#### Edit

As the answer below points out, what I'm looking for isn't exactly kerning.
I don't quite know what else to call it, so I'm justing going with 'spacing'.

My apologies.

Answer (score 3):

You may say:

```
\usepackage[kerning=alltext]{microtype}
\SetExtraKerning
  [ unit = space ]
  { encoding = * }
  { \textemdash = {500,500} }
```

Note that this will only adjust the kerning, without any stretch or shrink component as in your `\Dash` command. 
(**Edit**:)
And as this is exactly what you are looking for, this answer boils down to: No, at least with `microype` it is not possible to add stretchable and shrinkable space around a glyph.

Comment: Hmmm, then perhaps I'm using the wrong word :( My apologies; I'll edit the question appropriately.